# Use a model field to query another model field in django

Tags: python, django, orm

I have two models in our django app

```
class Reg(models.Model):
   transactions = ManyToMany
   price = IntegerField

class Transaction(models.Model)
   amount = IntegerField
```

Now I would like to make a lookup like:

```
Registration.objects.filter(reg__price==transaction__amount)
```

Previously we used the following approach:

- Registration has a property is_paid that computes wether a transaction with equal amount exists
- [r for r in Registration.objects.filter(...) if r.is_paid]

This is ofc very query-consuming and inefficient.
I wonder whether there would be a better way to do this!
Any hint is appreciated :)

Comment: You did not construct the fields, you should write `IntegerField()` and `ManyToMany('Transaction')`.

Comment: Furthermore it is not very clear when an invoice is paid? If the *sum* of the transactions sum up to `amount`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this was obviously pseudo-code. For the second though, well, if enough transaction amount exists to cover the price == paid

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`F` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) for such a query:

```
from django.db.models import F

Registration.objects.filter(price=F('transactions__amount'))
```

This will filter all `Registration` instances whose `price` is equal to one of their `transactions`' `amount`. If you want all transactions amounts' sum to be equal or more than the registration price, you can use annotations to [aggregate each registration's `Sum`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards):

```
paid_registrations = Registration.objects.\
   annotate(ta=Sum('transactions__amount')).\  # annotate with ta sum
   filter(price__lte=F('ta'))  # filter those whose price is <= that sum
```